# function productOfSums

Tags: arrays, c

The function `productOfSums` accepts two arguments - `SIZE` and `arr`, an integer representing the size of the integer array `arr` and the integer array `arr`. The array can be divided into two parts, where the first part of the array (starting from `0` to `i`) is in ascending order and the second part of the array (starting from `i` to `SIZE-1`) is in descending order.

The function `productOfSums` must find the sum of the first part F and the sum of the second part S. Finally, the function must return an integer representing the product of F and S. The function must return `-1` if the size of the array is less than `3`.

My Code:

```
int productofSums(int SIZE, int *arr)
{
    long int f = 0, s = 0;
    int i = 1;
    if (SIZE < 3)
       return -1;
    else
    {
        while (i < SIZE)   
        {
            if (arr[i] > arr[i - 1])
            {
                f + =arr[i]
            }
            i++;
            
            if (arr[i] < arr[i - 1])
            {
                s += arr[i];
            } 
        }
    } 
    return f * s;
}
```

Input:

```
7
4 7 15 11 10 5 2
```

Expected Output:

```
1118
```

Your program O/P:

```
728
```

The sum of integers in the first part of the array is `26` (`4 + 7 + 15`).

The sum of integers in the second part of the array is `43` (`15 + 11 + 10 + 5 + 2`).

The product of `26` and `43` is `1118`.

Comment: What is the specification for the problem this code is supposed to solve? How does the expected input produce the expected output?

Comment: Please indent your code properly so it is readable.

Comment: So, do you want to calculate (4+7+15)×(15+11+10+5+2)?

Comment: yeah i want to  know why and how 26 inside loop got converted to 263 outside the loop

Comment: I don't see any code calculating S, i.e. the sum of the descending  part.

Comment: @SrinivasanA You don't return a value.... didn't your compile complain with a warning? That is `return;` should be `return f * s;` but you never calculate `s` so that code will always return zero

Comment: You are required to complete the given code. You can click on Run anytime to check the compilation/execution status of the program. You can use printf to debug your code. The submitted code should be logically/syntactically correct and pass all test cases. Do not write the main() function as it is not required. //I tried that but did not get the correct output as it seems to pad the given integer of  with additional digit

Comment: In other words your code is missing something like: `if(arr[i]<arr[i-1]) {s+=arr[i];}`

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by ".... it seems to pad the given integer of with additional digit" Your output is "11 26 26 26 26 26" which makes sense. The first 11 comes from 4+7 and the first 26 comes from "11+15" (or "4+7+15"). The rest of the 26 comes because the code has entered the  descending part of the array, i.e. no further updates of `f`

Comment: BTW: If the same number can be in the input several times you should use `<=` instead of just `<`

Comment: product of (the sum of  ascending part and then sum of the descending part f,s) now my o/p is 728

Comment: @SrinivasanA please confirm that for `4 7 15 11 10 5 2` the _first part_ is `4 7 15` and the _second part_ is `11 10 5 2`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky The second part should also include 15. That is what is specified in the text and that explains the difference to the expected output as the revised code presumably misses to include 15 in the second part.

Comment: The sum of integers in the first part of the array is 26 (4 + 7 + 15).
The sum of integers in the second part of the array is 43 (15 + 11 + 10 + 5 + 2).
The product of 26 and 43 is 1118.

Comment: OT: The `i++;` should probably in the end of the `while`

Comment: OT: What should the result be from arrays like a) 1 2 3 4 b) 1 2 3 4 4 4 3 2 1

Comment: There is no question in the post. Stack Overflow is for asking specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

I can see some issues in the posted implementation. Every version of it.

For starters, it doesn't include the first element of the array in the sum of its ascending part, nor the peak value, in the descending one.

I'd write something like the following:

```
int productofSums(int SIZE,int *arr)
{
    if ( SIZE < 3 )
       return -1;
    
    int ascending_sum = arr[0];
    //                  ^^^^^^
    int i = 1;
    for ( ; i < SIZE  &&  arr[i] >= arr[i - 1]; ++i )
    { //                         ^^
      ascending_sum += arr[i];
    }

    int descending_sum = arr[i - 1];
    //                   ^^^^^^^^^^

    // Then, sum the following elements...
    
    // [ ... ] Not shown

    // Finally
    return ascending_sum * descending_sum;
}
```